# Ряд Тейлора выводит 0

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

Не могу понять как реализовать ряд Тейлора, прога всегда 0 выводит.
Вот условие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот попытка:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double epsilon (int n, int x, int k)
{
    double sum ;
    double sum_1;
    while (sum_1 < 0.1e-5)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        k++;
        
        sum += (double)(pow(x,k+2)) / (double)(((k+1*k+3)/(k+2*k+4)));

        sum_1*=(double)sum;
        }
    }
    return sum_1;
    }
int main()
{
    int n, x, k = 1;
    cin >> n >> x;
    cout << epsilon (x,k,n);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дополнение к предыдущим ораторам :)

Вам и вовсе не нужны эти вычисления с `pow` (впрочем, совершенно неверные — вы *пытались* вычислять очередной член просто как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что, как вы понимаете, совершенно не то, что написано в условии... но даже в этом случае надо писать скобки, так как приоритет умножения, как учат еще в начальной школе, выше приоритета сложения) — каждый следующий член легко вычисляется из предыдущего:

```
double arcsin(double x, double eps = 1e-7)
{

    double term = x, sum = term;
    x *= x;
    for(int k = 1; abs(term) > eps; k+=2)
        sum += (term *= x*k/(k+1))/(k+2);
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    for(double x = 0; x < 0.8; x += 0.1)
        cout << asin(x) << "    " << arcsin(x) << endl;
}
```

Результат работы программы [здесь](https://ideone.com/BELF3s).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в преобразованиях типов.

Посмотрим на строку

```
    sum += pow(x,k+2)/((k+1*k+3)/(k+2*k+4));
```

Там в правой части в знаменателе используются *только целые числа*. Это означает, что будет выполнена операция деления одного целого числа на другое целое.

Очевидно, это не совсем то, что Вы хотите сделать.

Имеет смысл прибегнуть к принудительному преобразованию типов, что то вроде

```
    sum += (double)(pow(x,k+2)) / (double)(((k+1*k+3)/(k+2*k+4)));
```

Ну, и во всех местах, где Вам нужно получить по смыслу `double` из `int` - примените преобразование типа в явном виде.

Но есть еще более простая и "смешная" проблема: Вы в функции нигде не возвращаете посчитанного значения.

Компилятор при этом выдаёт вам предупреждение, но, видимо, Вы не обратили на это внимания

Ну, и у Вас в функции неинициализированные переменные - как говорится, "типичная ошибка новичка". А неинициализированные переменные приводят к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: Странно, но преобразование не помогло, теперь выводит -nan

Answer (score 1):

1. `double epsilon (int n, double x, double k)`
2. `k+1*k+3` - в каком порядке будут выполнены действия?
3. Вычисления, конечно, неправильные. Вы что, не видите, что количество множителей в числителе и знаменателе растет?

Comment: Я то вижу, но я не совсем понимаю как это прописать можно

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII В таком случае надо не валять дурака, а говорить: вижу вот это вот здесь, а как сделать правильно - не знаю.

Comment: Хорошо, впредь так и буду делать, у меня была мысль использовать накопление суммы, что я и попытался сделать, но я так понимаю это был неверный шаг?

Comment: @КонстантинНиколаевичБоярII Это был верный шаг. Кроме суммы надо запоминать предыдущий член ряда и получать следующий член, домножая его на `х*х` и числа.