# Разложения arctan в ряд Тейлoра UNIX C

Tags: c, алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Разложение функции в ряд тейлера работает не стандартно в диапозонах выше `-1 <= and >= 1`
В википедии дан ряд тейлера и описание работы в области определения от минус бесконечности до плюс бесконечности, хотя по факту работает как и arcsin and arccos в диапозоне от `1` до `-1`;

```
long double my_atan(double x) {
  long double t_at = x, last = x;
  for (int k = 1; my_fabs(last) > EPS_10; ++k) {
    last *= -x * x * (2 * k - 1) / (2 * k + 1);
    t_at += last;
  }
  return t_at;
}
```

Я предпологаю что если функция циклично то от входящего значения просто на просто брать модуль и отдельно обрабатывать 1 и -1.

---

*Где я допускаю ошибку?* Как считать значения выше x >= 1

По советы Harry преобразовал в

```
long double atan(double x) { return asin(x / sqrt(1.0 + x * x)); }

long double s21_asin(double x) {
  long double term = x, sum = S21_NAN;
  if (-1.0 < x && x < 1.0) {
    sum = term;
    x *= x;
    for (int k = 1; s21_fabs(term) > EPS_10; k += 2)
      sum += (term *= x * k / (k + 1)) / (k + 2);
  } else if (x == 1.0) {
    sum = M_PI / 2.0;
  } else if (x == -1.0) {
    sum = -M_PI / 2.0;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Данный ряд действительно расходится при |x| > 1, а при близких к 1 значениях хоть и сходится, но медленно... но в чем ваш вопрос, поясните, пожалуйста?

Comment: @Harry.        Каким образом я могу считать atan для значений выше 1

Comment: Разделите область [-1,1] на зоны. Напишите разложение в ряд для каждой зоны отдельно, иначе вблизи границы, предется учитывать слишком много членов.. За пределами [-1;1], воспользовавшийся разложением arcctg(x)   `arctg(x) = arcctg(1/x)`

Comment: А! Выразив, например, через арксинус. arctg x = arcsin(x/sqrt(1+x^2)). Или иную функцию. Или иным способом. Но ряд Тейлора вблизи точки x=0 при |x|>1 расходящийся.

Comment: Ну например посмотреть как другие решали. https://elixir.bootlin.com/musl/v0.9.9/source/src/math/atan.c#L12

Comment: В примере выше арктангенс «неудобных» чисел представляют как сумму какой-то константы и арктангенса «удобного» числа для которого значение считают разложением в ряд.

Comment: @Harry.        Понравился способ через разложение, что позволяет мне проверять функции свои же в работе других вычеслений. Обновил Текст вопроса можешь посмотреть на реализации asin?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1358852/195342

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примените соотношение

```
atan(x) + atan(1/x) = Pi/2
```

т.е. для больших значений x используйте ряд

```
atan(x) = Pi/2 - 1/x + 3/x^3 - 5/x^5...
```

Как изменить функцию:

```
long double my_atan(double x) {
  int flag = 0;
  if (fabs(x) > 1) {
     x = 1/x; 
     flag = 1;
  }

  считаете, как прежде

  return flag? Pi/2 - t_at: t_at;
}
```

Comment: так американский сайт и сказал [Calculating  arctan(3)  using Taylor series](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/473390/1045886)

Comment: Плохо только, что при аргументах вблизи 1 сходимость будет слишком медленная...

Comment: @Harry Ну да, поэтому всякие приёмчики и применяют вроде вычисления через другие функции. Здесь, как я понимаю, задача стояла не обязательно пооптимальнее вычислить, а вообще результат получить.

Comment: @Harry не страшно, если очень хочется, то и вокруг единицы можно тейлора разложить `ArcTan[1 + x] = Pi/4 + x/2 - x^2/4 + x^3/12` *`(1+x>0)`*

Comment: @AlexGlebe Можно. А сходимость? Просто в результате получается сложная логика, где на что переключаться. Что, конечно, не умаляет достоинств ответа :)